# $|\mu|(E) := sup\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\mu (E_i)|\}$ for all $\{{E}_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ partition of $E$. $(X,\mathfrak M,\mu )$ is a measure space.

Tags: measure-theory

The definition of total variation of a complex measure $\mu $, where  $ (X, \mathfrak M, \mu ) $ is a measure space is

$ |\mu|(E) := sup\{  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\mu (E_i)|  \}   $ for all $   \{ {E}_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N} $ partition of $ E $.

The definition of complex measure $ \mu : \mathfrak M \longrightarrow \mathbb C $ is  $ \mu(E) := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu (E_i)    $ for all $   \{ {E}_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N} $ partition of $ E $. And this definition requires that the series be absolutely convergent.

My question is this:

Is it possible to display an example where a set E is written as two different partitions that generate different sums? that is, it's possible to write $ E = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i $, where $ \{ {E}_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N} $ and $ \{ {F}_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N} $ are different partitions of $ E $ such that

$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\mu (E_i)| \neq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\mu (F_i)| $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $\mu(A)=\displaystyle\int_{A}x^{3}dx$, we compute that $\mu([0,1])=1/4$, $\mu([-1,0))=-1/4$, $\mu([1/2,1])=15/64$, $\mu([-1,1/2))=-15/64$.

Comment: Wow! great counter-example! thank you so much!